# Iterate through a Result Set of MySQL by Clicking the Next Button in Php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, resultset

I am developing with php and mysql for the backend. I have a table [books] with more than 10 rows.
I want to view each book and its properties on the page. When I click the NEXT button, it should display another book and its properties. When I click the BACK button, it should return to the previous book.

Using:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_string)){
echo "<tr><td>Title</td>
<td>". $row['title']. "</td></tr>".
"<tr><td>Date</td>".
"<td>".$row['datePub']."</td></tr>"; 
}
```

will print out all the rows.

How can I iterate through each row using a button's clicked event perhaps?

thank you all.

Comment: Please switch to `mysqli_*` or `pdo` because `mysql_*` is deprectated and removed as of PHP7

Comment: learn pagination. and  with more than 10 rows or cols?

Comment: You might need to look at AJAX to fo this nicely

Comment: A good answer to this would requie a tutorial and maybe even a lecture. As such it is Off Topic for SO I am afraid

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use an AJAX request to get the needed data for your page.
2. If you don't want to use AJAX you can always get all the data from the database and filter it with a page count that you can pass as GET parameter.

The advantage with the first solution is that you don't have to reload the whole page.

Comment: Before I posted the question, I thought of using AJAX. But I needed to know other possible alternatives. So, I am working with AJAX now. But that would mean, loading the first row using the onLoad event, save the row_id in a Session var and, call the session var on the click event of either the Previous or Next Button. Thanks for your contributions so far. I appreciate.

Comment: You can store the page count in a session variable or, after you passed the pagecount from PHP to JS increment it and pass it back to PHP with document.getElementById("yourButton").setAttribute("onclick","yourFunction("+pageCount+")");

Comment: Thanks a lot, @K.O. Rolling.